# Как разделить столбец на два новых - с учётом того, какие данные внутри одной ячейки (строки) этого столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

У меня есть Series. В этом Series набор данных (рейтинг фильмов). Было обнаружено, что рейтинг фильмов имеет 2 типа: 1 тип - оценка пользователей (от 0 до 10); 2 тип - процент положительных рецензий. Получается, что в каждой строке указан либо 1, либо 2 тип рейтинга.
Я пытаюсь додуматься, как разделить эти два типа рейтинга между собой, чтобы потом можно было анализировать остальной фрейм данных с учётом типа рейтинга.
Для лучшего понимания приведу как пример уникальные значения этого Series:

```
df['ratings'].unique()
```

array(['7.2', '6.6', '6.8', '7.7', '8.3', '8.0', '7.8', '8.1', '7.1',
'6.0', '7.4', '5.8', '8.7', '6.3', '6.9', '5.0', '4.3', '7.3',
'7.0', '6.4', 0, '8.2', '7.5', '6.7', '7.9', '5.9', '6.2', '5.6',
'6.5', '2.4', '7.6', '6.1', '8.6', '8.5', '8.8', '5.5', '5.1',
'5.7', '5.4', '99%', '4.4', '4.5', '5.3', '4.1', '8.4', '2.6',
'3.8', '4.6', '4.8', '4.0', '3.0', '1.6', '4.2', '5.2', '4.7',
'4.9', '3.9', '2.7', '3.3', '2.9', '28%', '3.7', '1.4', '3.1',
'97%', '3.5', '3.2', '2.8', '1.5', '2.1', '2.5', '9.2', '3.4',
'1.1', '3.6', '83%', '64%', '91%', '94%', '62%', '79%', '90%',
'19%', '88%', '1.0', '89%', '1.3', '1.9', '1.8', '1.2', '1.7',
'9.0', '98%', '8.9', '9.1'], dtype=object)

Я так думаю, что, возможно, нужна какая-то своя новая функция? Но не выходит написать что-то нормальное, рабочее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
arr = pd.Series(['7.2', '6.6', '6.8'…
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df[1] = df[0].str.contains('%', na=False)
df
```

###### Вывод:

```console
    0   1
0   7.2 False
1   6.6 False
2   6.8 False
... ... ...
92  98% True
93  8.9 False
94  9.1 False
95 rows × 2 columns
```

`df[0][df[1]]`:

```console
39    99%
60    28%
64    97%
     ... 
83    88%
85    89%
92    98%
Name: 0, Length: 14, dtype: object
```

`df[0][~df[1]]`

```console
0     7.2
1     6.6
2     6.8
     ... 
91    9.0
93    8.9
94    9.1
Name: 0, Length: 81, dtype: object
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, для единообразного подхода к анализу рейтинга проще привести все к "одному знаменателю". Например, проценты к баллам. Т.е. `99%` станут `9.9` баллов. Также, поскольку во фрейме - текстовое представление чисел, его целесообразно конвертировать во `float` для возможности обработки как чисел (сравнения, сортировки, фильтрации, усреднения и т.д.).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ratings': ['7.2', '6.6', '6.8', '7.7', '8.3', '8.0', '7.8', '8.1', '7.1', '6.0', '7.4', '5.8',
                               '8.7', '6.3', '6.9', '5.0', '4.3', '7.3', '7.0', '6.4', '0', '8.2', '7.5', '6.7', '7.9',
                               '5.9', '6.2', '5.6', '6.5', '2.4', '7.6', '6.1', '8.6', '8.5', '8.8', '5.5', '5.1',
                               '5.7', '5.4', '99%', '4.4', '4.5', '5.3', '4.1', '8.4', '2.6', '3.8', '4.6', '4.8',
                               '4.0', '3.0', '1.6', '4.2', '5.2', '4.7', '4.9', '3.9', '2.7', '3.3', '2.9', '28%',
                               '3.7', '1.4', '3.1', '97%', '3.5', '3.2', '2.8', '1.5', '2.1', '2.5', '9.2', '3.4',
                               '1.1', '3.6', '83%', '64%', '91%', '94%', '62%', '79%', '90%', '19%', '88%', '1.0',
                               '89%', '1.3', '1.9', '1.8', '1.2', '1.7', '9.0', '98%', '8.9', '9.1']})
df.loc[mask, 'ratings'] = df.loc[(mask := df.ratings.str.endswith('%')), 'ratings'].str.strip('%').astype(float).div(10)
df.ratings = df.ratings.astype(float)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сначала мне показалось, что так не правильно будет делать. Но потом, подумав, решила что так действительно лучше.

Comment: К знаменателю можно привести, но это абсолютно разные значения судя по вопросу. Если говорить о том же Кинопоиске, оценка может быть высокой из-за стадного чувства или накруток, а по рецензиям понятно, что фильм УГ. И наоборот, какой-нибудь дикий артхаус будет с оценкой ниже плинтуса, а по проценту положительных рецензий окажется, что фильм то достоин внимания. В общем, я бы не смешивал и разделил на две колонки, иначе аналитика сомнительной может получится. А ещё лучше сделать 3 колонки: "Отзывы", "Рецензии" и приведённое к общему знаменателю. Тогда по трём могут быть интересные выводы.

Comment: @DiMithras если обогатить представленные автором данные, то да, можно рассматривать с разных сторон. Если брать исходные данные "как есть", то подход с разделением будет выглядеть однобоко - у каких-то фильмов только баллы, у каких-то проценты. А как сравнить фильмы с баллами с фильмами с процентами? Привести к одному варианту, видимо. Да, будет некоторая погрешность, но она исходно в любых оценках имеется.

Comment: @АлексейР вот поэтому лучше 3 колонки  Без обогащения по данным видно, что если привести к общему знаменателю, то в ТОП-5 будет 4 фильма по которым есть процент положительных рецензий, и только один фильм, по которому есть оценки. При том что в изначальной выборке рецензии составляют всего 17% от совокупности. Мне кажется тут чуть больше чем погрешность. Опять же возвращаясь к КП можно легко найти фильм с 100% рецензий, а максимальная оценка там за фильмы 9.2. Если есть желание сравнить и те и те, пожалуйста, но не стоит аналитику только на этом строить, а проверять гипотезы.

Comment: @DiMithras, я тоже думала о том, что, таким образом получается некорректный рейтинг. Плюс, нельзя будет описать по типу: зрители установили рейтинг фильму такой, зато критики его оценили на столько то процентов. Но потом, я посчитала какое количество этип процентов попало в этот столбец, оказалось менее 10% данных имеет 2 тип рейтинга (положительные рецензии). Я прикинула, что они не имеют такого большого значения (всего 10%).

Comment: @Kusi_pusi 17%. Но дело не столько в количестве, сколько в репрезентативности.